# Given a linear path with $n$ dots connected by $n-1$ lines, find the minimum number of coins required to win the game

Tags: graph-theory, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

Given a linear path with $n$ dots connected by $n-1$ lines, find the minimum number of coins required to win the game provided the game features are as follows:

- In the following game, you're given a linear path as mentioned above and a set of coins will be placed randomly on the dots by your friend. (You don't know the exact location of the dots as that's not controlled by you).
- **Aim of the game:** You win if you can bring at least one coin to the destinated dot (as set by your friend).
- Whenever you move a coin from a dot to its adjacent dot, you take off an existing coin in the current dot permanently (as a fee). If there's no coin to remove (as a fee), you can't move a coin from one dot to its adjoining dot.

---

I noted that if there are $n$ ***dots*** and $n-1$ straight lines joining them, then the minimum number of ***coins*** for which you can force/guarantee a win is $2^{n-1}$. It can be easily proved by doing a bit of a backward approach and then considering the extreme case.

***Q.:***: If the graph isn't a straight path, how would everything work in that case? Can we determine the **minimum** number of ***coins*** **required** if the initial positions of the coins aren't known (as that's chosen randomly by your friend) but the destined location (***dot***) is provided (yes, your friend will tell you, as can be noted from the second enumeration above)?

Comment: Looks like an interesting question but I'm not sure I understand all the details. What do you mean by not knowing the initial positions of the coins?

Comment: @ErlangWiratamaSurya I've edited the details of the game and the question that follows. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes it's clear now. I think the number itself depends on the "structure" of the tree in a non-trivial way, so it's difficult to give a "formula" for the number. But I got a polynomial-time algorithm (w.r.t number of vertices) that finds the desired number. Is this good enough for your purposes?

Comment: @ErlangWiratamaSurya Sure, that would be pretty much appreciated. I don't have any specific purpose. Just trying to explore this. It's dependent on the "structure", so, any forms of generalization/specific case consideration would be intriguing.

Comment: I just realised there's an error in my argument, but this might help.
Suppose that the tree is $T$ and the destined vertex is $r$. Define $f(T,r,i)$ to be the minimum number of coins required to guarantee that we can eventually have $i$ coins at $r$. Let $r_1,...,r_n$ be the child of $r$ in the tree $T$ with root $r$ and let $T_1,...,T_n$ be the corresponding sub-tree. It is easy to see that $f(T,r,1)=(\sum_{i=1}^n f(T_i,r_i,2)-1)+1$ with PHP and construction. Originally I thought $f(T_i,r_i,2)=2f(T_i,r_i,1)$, which will lead to a polytime algo. But I think this is not the case.

Comment: Notice that solving $f(T,r,1)$ in sense forces you to find $f(T_i,r_i,2)$, i.e. a configuration with $f(T,r,1)-1$ coins that's not winnable directly gives a configuration for $f(T_i,r_i,2)-1$ for all $T_i$ s.t. we can't have 2 coins at $r_i$. So they're equally difficult.

Comment: True. But the number of subtrees may increase. It's hard in that case. Can a large case be provided which does a generalization of some particular cases?

Comment: How about considering: $g(n,k)$ which means the root node has $n$ nodes and each node, thereafter, has $n$ children. And then, each children will have $n$ each.. and that follows. And $k$ represents the total number of steps from the root node to the farthest children in the farthest sub-tree

Comment: Would the minimum number of coins required force a win be two raised to the length of the longest minimum length path between the destined location and any other vertex of the graph?

Comment: @BobKrueger Yes, it seems like that only. But that kind of depends on $n$. So, it may not always be true.

Comment: @BobKrueger That's not true in general. If you consider the graph $S_4$ with one of the leaf as the destined location, then the length of the longest minimum length path between the destined location and any other vertex of the graph is 2. But we need at least $5> 2^2$ coins to guarantee a win.

Comment: @ErlangWiratamaSurya How about considering: $g(n,k)$ which means the root node has $n$ nodes and each node, thereafter, has $n$ children. And then, each children will have $n$ each.. and that follows. And $k$ represents the total number of steps from the root node to the farthest children in the farthest sub-tree. When $k=n$, i.e., can we compute for $f(n,n)$? I think it's possible.

Comment: Any thoughts on the structure I commented above?

Comment: I now see the complications. I think I have a solution for trees. Are you looking for an answer for general graphs as well?

Comment: @BobKrueger Anything would be appreciated gladly. But kindly explain the structure (such that it's understood clearly, unlike the one i just mentioned above) for which you'll be showing your result. Else it's hard to go through the result/proof/claim

Comment: @BobKrueger Sure, that would be helpful! (this post will be removed shortly)